# Angular + Bootstrap = No Images

Tags: html, angularjs, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Angular material design card. When I pull an image into my HTML template using 'src,' it shows on desktop but not on any mobile browser. When I go to the actual URL, the image exists on my server, so I know the problem isn't the path of the image.

When I change 'src' to either 'ng-src' or 'data-ng-src,' the image does not show on mobile or desktop. The template is very simple; and like I mentioned, the image path leads to the exact image on my server. Is there something key I am missing?

```
<md-card>
    <div class="panel-heading menu_header">{{item.entree}}</div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x info"></i>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/media/{{item.primary_image}}"
                 alt="{{item.entree}}">

            <p class="menu_desc price-widget" id="slidemarginleft">{{item.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">{{item.side}}</div>
    <div class="center" style="margin-bottom: 7px;">
        <div class="input-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="numbers-row">
                <div class="dec increment input-group-btn col-md-3 col-xs-7">-</div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1">
                    <input class="form-control cart-qty" id="{{item.meal_type}}" type="text"
                           name="{{item.meal_type}}" min="0" max="21" value="{{sub.pork}}">
                </div>
                <div class="inc increment input-group-btn col-md-3">+</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'ng-src' to interpolate expressions.

```
<img ng-src="/media/{{item.primary_image}}" />
```

Comment: That didn't help -- it actually made everything on the page blank.

Comment: Whoops, try the updated version. ;) ng-src is what you want. Of course there could be issues server-side as well.

Comment: That's what I tried first, but it just shows the alt tag and not the image.

Comment: I can't see a reason for that not to work with the code provided. It's likely a URL issue. Try going into the inspector and seeing if you can open the image by clicking on the URL directly. Also check the Resources tab/ > Frames/ > [page name] / > images and see if the images are loading there (I'm assuming you are using chrome)

Comment: You're correct -- when I use 'src,' the image loads in the Resources > Frames tab, but when I use 'ng-src,' the image is not there even though the URL/path is exactly the same. Not sure why that would happen...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103536/discussion-between-acs254-and-rorschach120).

Comment: Strange. Well if the image is loading then check your CSS. Use the editor to make the img element a block and change the size. Se if it appears. From there I'd have to see your CSS/design idea to actually tell you how to style it.